# What is the need of Wildcard type parameters (<?>) in Java?

Tags: java, wildcard

I've recently learnt about wildcards in Java and I understand the concept But can't seem to figure out why they're introduced, Can't we just use the Object class (or respective parent class ) in the parameter of a function.

Comment: "Can't we just use the Object class (or respective parent class ) in the parameter of a function." No, because a `List<String>` isn't a `List<Object>`, but it is a `List<? extends Object>` aka `List<?>`.

Comment: Okay, Now I understand so it specifically answers this type of problem posed by collections,thank you @AndyTurner

Comment: Not just collections: any generic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards make methods more flexible in the parameters they accept.

Consider this method:

```
void printList(List<Object> list) {
  for (Object object : list) System.out.println(object);
}
```

Currently, this will only accept a `List<Object>` as a parameter:

```
printList(Arrays.asList(new Object()));  // OK
printList(Arrays.asList(""));            // Not OK
```

But there isn't really a good reason for such a prohibition: inside `printList`, you don't *really* care what kinds of `Object` the list elements are, because you can print *any* `Object`.

So, if you declare the `list` parameter using a wildcard:

```
// List<?> is the same as List<? extends Object>.
void printListWildcard(List<?> list) {
```

then you can pass in a `List` with whatever element type you like:

```
printListWildcard(Arrays.asList(new Object()));  // Still OK
printListWildcard(Arrays.asList(""));            // Now OK
```

Wildcards *can* also be used in other places, e.g. return types; but they should be avoided in return types because you then can't get rid of the wildcard (e.g. if you declare a variable to hold the result of a wildcard-returning method).